# Java reflection, getting the method append and use it

Tags: java, reflection

I've wrote a program and it must ask the Method to be used ( i use the java.lang.StringBuffer.append) then it must say how many params it max needs, this is 3 in this case I think. The user may type as many arguments as he wants all strings, then the program append them and print the string out. But there is something wrong and I just don't find the error.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import tio.*;
public class MethodExecutor {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException
    {
        String input = "";
        String input1 = "";
        String input2 = "";
        String argumenten[];
        int aantal = 0;
        System.out.println("What method to invoke?");
        input = Console.in.readLine();

        input1 = input.substring(0,input.lastIndexOf("."));
        input2 = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(".")+1,input.length());
        System.out.println(input2);

        Class<?> c = Class.forName(input1);
        Method m = c.getMethod(input2, null);
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = m.getParameterTypes();

        System.out.println("Needs max " + parameterTypes.length + " parameters.");
        System.out.println("How many will you provide?");
        aantal = Console.in.readInt();
        argumenten = new String[aantal];
        for(int i = 0; i < argumenten.length; i++)
            argumenten[i] = Console.in.readLine();

        System.out.println("Success");

        }
}
```

Tio is just a lib to get console input.

Could someone please help?

Kind regards,

Comment: And what is wrong, what is the behavior and what are you expecting?

Comment: I can't show the max need parameters that .append will take. So I also can't execute the function with the params given by the user. I think the .getmethod doesn't give me the right function

Answer (score 2):

I think that this ...

```
Method m = c.getMethod(input2, null);
```

... is going to look for a method with the name stored in input2, which takes no arguments.

Instead I think you'll need to search EVERY method on the Class, and then print out the lengths of the ones with matching names

(from getMethod's javadoc:)

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object. The name parameter is a String specifying the simple name of the desired method. The parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared order.
>   If parameterTypes is null, it is treated as if it were an empty array.

Comment: So I need to search with getdeclaredmethods everything and then with if tests, test if there is a method called append?